# What are the default SharePoint groups applicable for communications site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, groups, communication-site

Link: [Permission levels for default SharePoint groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default-sharepoint-groups#permission-levels-for-default-sharepoint-groups)

Above link shows the groups available for team sites.

What are the default SharePoint groups applicable for communications site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below groups are available by default for SharePoint communications sites:

- `<site name>` Owners
- `<site name>` Members
- `<site name>` Visitors

[image]

Comment: Which group is responsible to create lists, document libraries? and which group is responsible to add content into the list, document libraries?

Comment: It depends on the permissions levels. By default Owners group have "Full Control" permissions, Members group have "Edit" permissions and Visitors have "Read" permissions. Any group/user having "Edit" or higher permissions can create lists/libraries and any group/user having "Contribute" and higher permissions can add content into the lists/libraries. For more info, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels